# Enter key capture for lightning input tag

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

How can I capture the enter key press action in the js controller for lightning:input text. below is the code in the component file.

```
 <div class="slds-form-element">
       <lightning:input aura:id="firstNameId" label="First Name" 
                 value="{!v.firstName}" placeholder="First Name"/>
 </div>
  <div class="slds-form-element"  >
      <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Search" 
                 onclick="{! c.buttonAction }" />

  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The lightning:input component has an onchange attribute:

> The action triggered when a value attribute changes.

component.cmp

```
<lightning:input label="Name" name="myname" onchange="{! c.changeHandler }"/>
```

controller.js

```
changeHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
    validate that enterKey was pressed and do some action

}
```

the documentation for the component can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm)

you can use [keycode.info](http://keycode.info/) for checking character codes, as to actually identifying the key value in your function, you can refer to [Working with Events in Javascript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_event.htm)

UPDATE: for some reason, unable to fetch Key event parameters when using lightning input.

Workaround is to wrap the component in an HTML tag that supports onkeypress events:

> All HTML elements, EXCEPT:
>
> ```
> <base>, <bdo>, <br>, <head>, <html>, <iframe>, <meta>, <param>, <script>, <style>, and <title>
> ```

and a us the event.which property to listen for the pressed key

```
<div onkeypress="{!c.controllerMethod}">
    <lightning:input --attributes-- />
</div>
```

Tested and works (Winter '18)

Comment: thanks for pointing in the right direction. Tried to get the key in js controller in following ways but was not successful. Any help is appreciated.                                      
         console.log("key = "+event.keycode.info);
        console.log("key = "+event.key);
        console.log("key = "+event.getParam('key'));

Comment: if (event.keyCode === 13) {} This should work. You can give a try

Comment: @brahmaji tammana, you cant fetch the keycode that way, close, but no cigar. Please check [working with events in javascript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_event.htm)

Comment: I tried the below ways to get the keycode but all of them were pretty much returning undefined. can you pls let me know how can I get the key code.                  console.log('params = '+JSON.stringify(event.getParams()));           
console.log('key = '+event.getParam("keyCode"));           
console.log('key = '+event.getParam("keycode"));           
console.log('key = '+event.getParam("key"));

Comment: @sfdcdev : The joys of testing Beta components =P

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed in below way .You get the value of key.
When u click on a key there is a event so you need to capture that event in your

```
component.cmp


<aura:application >
<ui:inputText label="Name" aura:id="name" keydown="{!c.getInput}"/>
 </aura:application>


controller.js
Controller for the above code
({
handleChange : function(cmp, event,helper) {
           var txtstrg = cmp.find("myinput").get("v.value");
            if(txtstrg.length>0){  
             var gtAsci= txtstrg.substr(txtstrg.length - 1)
              console.log(gtAsci.charCodeAt(0));
            } 
        }   


})
```

Let me know in case of further input.

Comment: Tried console.log('key = '+event.getParams().keyCode); for which I got undefined in the console log. Not sure if I have to add any code in the .cmp file. Please let me know if that is case.

Comment: <aura:application >
<ui:inputText label="Name" aura:id="name" keydown="{!c.getInput}"/>
 </aura:application>   "Please use KeyDown event to capture it .You will get the output in the console of the browser"

Comment: with ui:inputText I was able to get the key, but I could not get with lightning:input which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Here you go : Call the below Controller Code for onChange event . handleChange : function(cmp, event,helper) { var validity = cmp.find("myinput").get("v.value"); if(validity.length>0){ var inval= validity[validity.length-1]; console.log(inval.charCodeAt(0));} }for lightning :input use <div class="slds-form-element"> <lightning:input name="input" aura:id="myinput" label="Enter some text" onchange="{!c.handleChange}" /> </div>.Let me know if still u have any concern

Comment: @sfdcdev Plz vote this answer if it solve your problem